# Removing specfic nodes from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

**Removing specfic nodes from xml using xslt**

my question has two part

1)removing specfic nodes from xml using xslt

2)once the xslt is ready , this has to be done in runtime the node values to be removed will be passed as parameter

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <Category>History</Category>        
    </Header>
    <Body  messagetype="Personal">
        <Books>
            <Book>
                <authorDetails>
                    <title>The white tiger</title>
                    <author>Arvind Adiga</author>                   
                </authorDetails>                
                    <sellerDetails sellerType="Private">
                        <address >
                            <country>India</country>
                            <city>chennai</city>
                            </address >                     
                </sellerDetails>
                <identification>                    
                    <isbnNumber>AAAA1234</isbnNumber>                   
                </identification>
            </Book>
            <Book>
                <authorDetails>
                    <title>The white tiger</title>
                    <author>Arvind Adiga</author>                   
                </authorDetails>                
                    <sellerDetails sellerType="Private">
                        <address >
                            <country>India</country>
                            <city>chennai</city>
                            </address >                     
                </sellerDetails>
                <identification>                    
                    <isbnNumber>BBB12343</isbnNumber>                   
                </identification>
            </Book>
        </Books>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

The above is the sample xml 
the isbn number willbe passed on dynamically ,
and the xslt should be able to get the values of the isbn number as parameter in java code and remove the specific nodes in runtime and tranform the xml with out the nodes passed on.

sorry about puting botht the question in the same place
it willbe handy if i get answers separately

SO far i have managed to create this XSLt which returns all the values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="codes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="segment">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($codes, code/@Value)" /> <!-- Do nothing -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Martin thats 100 marks for the answer you gave ,and it worked nicely, 
i still have a problem that i gave an exmaple xml for simplicity/security reasons here, but the original xml i am working with has namespace and 
also how ant the isbn number is not direct element as mentioned here

Please see below the original xml and transformed xml after applying the xslt 
**original xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dt:Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="urn:aaaaaaaa" xmlns="urn:bbbbbbb" xmlns:cm="urn:cccccccc" xmlns:stf="dddddd" ">
    <Header>
        <Category>History</Category>        
    </Header>
    <dt:Body >
        <Books>
            <Book>
                <authorDetails>
                    <cm:Birth>
                        <cm:BirthDate>
                            <cm:DateYMD>1988-01-01</cm:DateYMD>
                        </cm:BirthDate>
                    </cm:Birth>
                    <cm:Address addressType="residential">
                        <cm:CountryCode>GB</cm:CountryCode>
                        <cm:AddressStruct>
                            <cm:Street>london</cm:Street>                           
                            <cm:PostCode>sddas</cm:PostCode>
                            <cm:City>london</cm:City>
                        </cm:AddressStruct>
                    </cm:Address>
                    <cm:Name>
                        <cm:NameFree>James Bond</cm:NameFree>
                    </cm:Name>              
                </authorDetails>
                <sellerDetails>
                    <sellerDetail sellerType="Private">
                    </sellerDetail>
                </sellerDetails>
                <BookSpec>
                    <stf:BookTypeIndic>2</stf:BookTypeIndic>
                    <stf:BookRefId>AAAAAA111111111</stf:BookRefId>
                    <stf:BookCorrRefId>BBBBBB2222222222</stf:BookCorrRefId>
                </BookSpec>
            </Book>

            <Book>
                <authorDetails>
                    <cm:Birth>
                        <cm:BirthDate>
                            <cm:DateYMD>1995-01-01</cm:DateYMD>
                        </cm:BirthDate>
                    </cm:Birth>
                    <cm:Address addressType="residential">
                        <cm:CountryCode>GB</cm:CountryCode>
                        <cm:AddressStruct>
                            <cm:Street>ripper Street</cm:Street>                            
                            <cm:PostCode>sddas</cm:PostCode>
                            <cm:City>london</cm:City>
                        </cm:AddressStruct>
                    </cm:Address>
                    <cm:Name>
                        <cm:NameFree>James Bond</cm:NameFree>
                    </cm:Name>              
                </authorDetails>
                <sellerDetails>
                    <sellerDetail sellerType="Private">
                    </sellerDetail>
                </sellerDetails>
                <BookSpec>
                    <stf:BookTypeIndic>2</stf:BookTypeIndic>
                    <stf:BookRefId>CCCCCC33333333</stf:BookRefId>
                    <stf:BookCorrRefId>DDDDDD4444444</stf:BookCorrRefId>
                </BookSpec>
            </Book>


            <Book>
                <authorDetails>
                    <cm:Birth>
                        <cm:BirthDate>
                            <cm:DateYMD>1995-01-01</cm:DateYMD>
                        </cm:BirthDate>
                    </cm:Birth>
                    <cm:Address addressType="residential">
                        <cm:CountryCode>GB</cm:CountryCode>
                        <cm:AddressStruct>
                            <cm:Street>ripper Street</cm:Street>                            
                            <cm:PostCode>sddas</cm:PostCode>
                            <cm:City>london</cm:City>
                        </cm:AddressStruct>
                    </cm:Address>
                    <cm:Name>
                        <cm:NameFree>James Bond</cm:NameFree>
                    </cm:Name>              
                </authorDetails>
                <sellerDetails>
                    <sellerDetail sellerType="Private">
                    </sellerDetail>
                </sellerDetails>
                <BookSpec>
                    <stf:BookTypeIndic>2</stf:BookTypeIndic>
                    <stf:BookRefId>EEEEEE555555555</stf:BookRefId>
                    <stf:BookCorrRefId>FFFFFF66666666666</stf:BookCorrRefId>
                </BookSpec>
            </Book>     
        </Books>
    </dt:Body>
</dt:Message>
```

**Transformed xml  when passing the parameters  {" 'CCCCCC33333333' ,  'EEEEEE555555555' "}**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dt:Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="urn:aaaaaaaa" xmlns="urn:bbbbbbb" xmlns:cm="urn:cccccccc" xmlns:stf="dddddd" ">
    <Header>
        <Category>History</Category>        
    </Header>
    <dt:Body >
        <Books>
            <Book>
                <authorDetails>
                    <cm:Birth>
                        <cm:BirthDate>
                            <cm:DateYMD>1988-01-01</cm:DateYMD>
                        </cm:BirthDate>
                    </cm:Birth>
                    <cm:Address addressType="residential">
                        <cm:CountryCode>GB</cm:CountryCode>
                        <cm:AddressStruct>
                            <cm:Street>london</cm:Street>                           
                            <cm:PostCode>sddas</cm:PostCode>
                            <cm:City>london</cm:City>
                        </cm:AddressStruct>
                    </cm:Address>
                    <cm:Name>
                        <cm:NameFree>James Bond</cm:NameFree>
                    </cm:Name>              
                </authorDetails>
                <sellerDetails>
                    <sellerDetail sellerType="Private">
                    </sellerDetail>
                </sellerDetails>
                <BookSpec>
                    <stf:BookTypeIndic>2</stf:BookTypeIndic>
                    <stf:BookRefId>AAAAAA111111111</stf:BookRefId>
                    <stf:BookCorrRefId>BBBBBB2222222222</stf:BookCorrRefId>
                </BookSpec>
            </Book>     
        </Books>
    </dt:Body>
</dt:Message>
```

Comment: You say "nodes" in plural. Will this be a string? If yes, can you show us how exactly will it be formatted? Or perhaps you'd rather have the codes inanother XML document, and pass the path to this document as the parameter?

Comment: Why do you have `match="segment"` in the XSLT but no `segment` element in the XML input sample?

Comment: @Martin Honnen -sorry  the match should be made on books as  match ="Book"

Comment: yes , the nodes can be in another xml or comma separated string , but its not finalzied yet.but if i pass ISBN -BBB12343 as parameter the xslt should take this value or list of values and remove the node and create the new xml using xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaG7:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="isbns-to-remove" select="'BBB12343'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Book">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(concat(',', $isbns-to-remove, ','), concat(',', identification/isbnNumber, ',')))">
          <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can pass in a string with single ISBN number or a string with a comma separated list of ISBN numbers and the stylesheet will only copy those `Book` elements to the result where `identification/isbnNumber` is not contained in the parameter.

As you have now posted a more complex XML input sample using namespaces the paths in the XSLT code need to be adapted:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:df="urn:bbbbbbb"
    xmlns:stf="dddddd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="df stf">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="isbns-to-remove" select="'CCCCCC33333333,EEEEEE555555555'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="df:Book">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(concat(',', $isbns-to-remove, ','), concat(',', df:BookSpec/stf:BookRefId, ',')))">
          <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin thats 100 % for the answer you gave ,and it worked nicely,

Comment: Martin thats 100 marks for the answer you gave ,and it worked nicely, 
i still have a problem that i gave an exmaple xml for simplicity/security reasons here, but the original xml i am working with has namespace and 
also how ant the isbn number is not direct element as mentioned here 


 please see the changed xml ..i have edited the question now .how the original xml  look

Comment: Please edit the question and provide well-formed samples of XML input and wanted output, currently you have changed the output sample in a few places, it is not clear whether you want to transform some elements from the input to have a different namespace in the output or whether you simply need to select elements in a namespace.

Comment: Martin - i have now edited the original question with the input xml and the output xml after  transformation ,the namespsace should be same in both the input and output xml only the nodes with elements passed should be removed from the input xml and transformed xml should be the output xml with removed nodes.

Comment: @sathishkumarnatarajan, I have edited my answer and have added a second XSLT sample to show how to use the approach with the XML with namespaces you have added to your question.

Comment: ,the xslt you gave worked nicely with the input xml i have posted in the question, but for some reason its not transofrming the real xml i have it in my project . i am not ina position to post the xml ..but its not trnaforming my xml not sure why ..i had careful look at the xslt you posted and did the necessary changes for my project specific xml  but NO luck .. is there anyway i can send the xml to you

Comment: Make sure you adapt all namespace declarations (`xmlns="..."`, `xmlns:foo="..."`), then I am sure it works out.

Comment: -thanks martin the solution worked. if i am using this solution in my j2ee application ,i will have a method like **removeRecords**(originalXml,xslt, list _of_records_to_be_removed) how to pass the list_of_records_to_be_removed , could you point me to some example

Comment: @sathishkumarnatarajan, ask a new question about J2EE if you really can't solve that yourself, there are online tutorials showing how to use JAXP.

Comment: Cheers @Martin Honnen- is there anything i have to do for this question,i am convinced with this answer

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work on how to accept an answer that works for you.

Comment: using the original xml and xslt i am able to get the tranformed xml after removing the nodes that contain elements as parameter in the xslt.
Is there is any way i can get two transformed xml
 1) XML(nodes) with out the elements passed as parameter and
 2)Another xml(nodes) with only the elements passed as parameter